# Form in form - solve differently?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have situation like this:

1. form with textbox, two dropdowns and grid with selected values
2. form with search textbox, which needs to know values selected in dropdowns in above form to do searching

First form is for saving whole data to database.
Second form is for searching in database, showing searched values and adding selected values to grid in first form.

It could work if form in form were allowed, but it is not.
I have tried to add hidden values for selected ids in this dropdowns but those values are not binded.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have solved that problem with code below for search part of the form:

Javascript:

```
$('#wsSearch').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Definition")',
        data: {
            word: $('#wsSearchWord').val(),
            firstId: $('#wsFirstDropdown').val(),
            secondId: $('#wsSecondDropdown').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#wsSearchResultContainer').html(data);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual PartialViewResult Search(string word, int firstId, int secondId)
{
    var model = this.service.Search(word, firstId, secondId);
    return PartialView("_SearchResult", model.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, but I guess you won't get this without JavaScript. With JavaScript, you could bind on submit events of the search form and then fetch the data from the first form or you could bind on change events of the dropdowns and then change the search form.

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid so ;) I have changed my thinking about it and find a solution with javascript :)